# How Does Gandalf Keep Getting his Staff Back?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings

In **The Lord of the Rings**, Gandalf notably *loses* his staff to Saruman. But he has it back later (notably after The Fellowship leaves Rivendell & enters the Mines of Moria, where he uses it to light their way).

I haven't seen 'the extended version'; does it show him using his Maia powers to manifest a new staff? or did he get it some other way?

Comment: Prime shipping.

Comment: Pretty much all of Gandalf's staves are gifted to him, mostly from the Elves. There are huge differences between the books and the films w.r.t. how/when Gandalf loses possession of each staff, as well as the amount of power they contain / allow for him to weld. In short, not much at all is revealed in the films regarding any of this.

Answer (score 7):

I do not believe the extended version shows us how, but the staff taken by Saruman is different from the one used until he falls into the chasm in Moria.

[Gandalf in the Shire](https://www.odt.co.nz/sites/default/files/styles/odt_portrait_medium_3_4/public/story/2016/04/sir_ian_mckellen_as_gandalf_in_the_hobbit_an_unexp_517a2dba73.JPG?itok=iiiaFWJS)

[Gandalf in Moria](https://i0.wp.com/voyagecomics.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Gandalf-gandalf-12059929-960-404.jpg?fit=720%2C303&ssl=1)

(Links rather than embedded because I'm not sure of the licensing of the photos)

You can clearly tell from the photos that although they are both rough wooden staffs, the shape of the head is very different. The Moria staff is more open at the top, and he places a crystal there which he uses for light.

I think we can therefore presume that he made or was gifted a new staff.

Comment: You know, you can make those links into images. It'd be the same as far as licensing is concerned. Probably.

Comment: Yeah. If someone doesn't want their image displayed, they'll block sharing (or not share it at all).

Answer (score 1):

Gandalf **never** lost his staff in the book. However, Gandalf later destroyed his staff in Moria while facing the Balrog in the chasm and subsequently after. After being restored to life he was taken to Lorien where Galadriel and the Elves gave him new clothing and apparently a new staff (Hence why he's wearing white robes).

In the movie he receives Several Replacements, Presumably the staff is just a stick, used as a conjuring tool, a conduit of power. Notice in the movies Gandalf uses no abilities of Magic without his staff rarely.